# Remove Min and Max in group by

Tags: sql

I am trying to get a total hours from a dataset and because you can have the same asset with the same company (company_B) twice at two different times I have this join issue. I know I want the min for company_B gone and the Max for company_B gone because they represent wrong dates being matched. The negative is easy but what about the Max?

I have:

AssetID------StartDate-------FinishDate-------CompanyName----HoursOnSite

22222-------2016-02-12-------2016-02-20-------Company_A--------192

22222-------2016-02-01-------2016-02-09-------Company_B--------208 (keep)

22222-------2016-02-12-------2016-02-09-------Company_B-------(-56) (remove)

22222-------2016-02-01-------2016-02-21-------Company_B--------480 (remove)

22222-------2016-02-12-------2016-02-21-------Company_B--------216 (keep)

55555-------2016-02-18-------2016-02-22-------Company_C--------96

99584-------2016-02-22-------2016-02-25-------Company_D--------63

Comment: Along with what you tried, what SQL server are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do the query for the records with max and min HoursOnSite for company B, and use (not in) or not equal to exclude those records.

If you still have concern, please paste your query.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that there has to be atleast 3 instances of unique assetid - companyname combination for the Max, Min filters to work. You can change it in the final where statement tO suit your requirement

```
WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,count(CompanyName) OVER (PARTITION BY AssetID,CompanyName) AS a
    FROM <TABLE_NAME>
    )
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE HoursOnSite NOT IN (
        SELECT MAX(HoursOnSite)
        FROM <TABLE_NAME>
        )
    AND gdp NOT IN (
        SELECT min(HoursOnSite)
        FROM <TABLE_NAME>
        )
    AND a > 2 --MODIFY AS PER YOUR REQUIREMENT
```